# Getting JSON from HTTP Discord.Js

Tags: json, discord.js

Im making a discord bot, and I have a URL here which has some raw json: [link here](http://ric.pikapools.com/api/stats) and I want one of the values (hashrateString) to be put inside a embed like:

hashrateString: 1GH

is there a way to do that and if so how?

Answer (score 1):

I never tried this with an external link but it should work the same way.

FIRST: write somewhere high up in your code this line

```
var fs = require('fs');
var data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('http://ric.pikapools.com/api/stats', 'utf8'));
```

After you can basically do whatever you want with your new object. There was no hashrateString: 1GH, but hashrateString: 4.68 GH should be accessible with data.algos.primesr.hashrateString (*Output: 4.68 GH*)

If it, for some weird reason, doesn't accept an URL, just try to copy&paste the text in a json file if possible, and use the path to it

Comment: It wont allow me to get the file from the URL. I know I can put it into a json file, but the point of it using the URL is because that URL will update every few minutes, and I want the stuff shown on my bot to update with it

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by specifying a constant to be the JSON from the url using node-fetch

```
const ricp = await fetch('http://ric.pikapools.com/api/stats').then(response => response.json());
```

and find an object in the JSON using

```
message.channel.send(ricp.algos.primesr.hashrateString)
```